# Bit masking in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, bitwise-operators

I have this query

```
SELECT * FROM "functions" WHERE (models_mask & 1 > 0)
```

and the I get the following error:

> PGError: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying & integer
>   HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

The models_mask is an integer in the database. How can I fix this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check out the [docs on bit operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-bitstring.html) for Pg.

Essentially `&` only works on two like types (usually bit or int), so `model_mask` will have to be `CAST`ed from varchar to something reasonable like bit or int:

`models_mask::int & 1` *-or*- `models_mask::int::bit & b'1'`

You can find out what types an operator works with using `\doS` in `psql`

```
pg_catalog | &    | bigint                      | bigint                      | bigint                      | bitwise and
pg_catalog | &    | bit                         | bit                         | bit                         | bitwise and
pg_catalog | &    | inet                        | inet                        | inet                        | bitwise and
pg_catalog | &    | integer                     | integer                     | integer                     | bitwise and
pg_catalog | &    | smallint                    | smallint                    | smallint                    | bitwise and
```

Here is a quick example for more information

```
# SELECT 11 & 15 AS int, b'1011' & b'1111' AS bin INTO foo;
SELECT

# \d foo
      Table "public.foo"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 int    | integer | 
 bin    | "bit"   | 

# SELECT * FROM foo;
 int | bin  
-----+------
  11 | 1011
```